# Custom phone number placeholder for WooCommerce my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, placeholder

I am trying to add a placeholder to phone number in my account page.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_phone_fields', 'override_default_address_my account_fields', 20, 1);
function override_default_address_my_account_fields( $address_fields ) {
     $address_fields['shop-phone']['placeholder'] = '+123456789';
     return $address_fields;
}
```

This code has not change the place holder. Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show the code of your page?

Comment: you mean the source code ?

Comment: <p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
        <label for="shop-phone">Phone Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="phone" id="shop-phone"      value="" required="required" />
    </p>

Answer (score 1):

You can try use wordpress filter `woocommerce_billing_fields`:

```
add_filter(  'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_my_account_fields', 20, 1 );
function custom_my_account_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = '+123456789';
    return $fields;
}
```

Hope it's help you. I checked It's work

Comment: Thanks, but it has changed the phone placeholder in checkout page not register/ my account page

Comment: @ash By default, there is no phone field in myaccount registration section located on [`myaccount/form-login.php` template file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/myaccount/form-login.php) … So this field has been added by you or a third party plugin and you will have to find out yourself how to manage that, as nobody can guess that by magic.

Comment: I havenot add that. Its available in multi vendor version.